# Resolving the Non-nullable instance field 'allDay' must be initialized error in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error that I don't know how to get rid of. I have tried what the error message suggests but the error remains. I have initialized allDay to false, I have made it a late variable but nothing helps.

The error message is flagged midway down the code and I have marked it with <<<< ERROR APPEARS HERE but the error is because of the bool allDay variable.

This is the error message:

```
Non-nullable instance field 'allDay' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.
```

Here is the class code:

```
class Events {
  String? id;
  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? location;
  late bool allDay;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  Events({
    this.id,
    this.eventName,
    this.eventStartTime,
    this.eventDuration,
    this.eventDate,
    this.eventDescription,
    this.location,
    required this.allDay,
    this.userId,
    this.companyId,
  });

  // Reading data from firebase and converting it into Event type
  factory Events.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
    return Events(
      id: id,
      eventName: doc['eventName'],
      eventStartTime: (doc['eventStartTime'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDuration: doc['eventDuration'],
      eventDate: (doc['eventDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDescription: doc['eventDescription'],
      location: doc['location'],
      allDay: doc['allDay'],
      userId: doc['userId'],
      companyId: doc['companyId'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'location': location,
      'allDay': allDay,
      'agentId': userId,
      'agencyId': companyId,
    };
  }

  Events copyWith({
    String? eventName,
    DateTime? eventStartTime,
    String? eventDuration,
    DateTime? eventDate,
    String? eventDescription,
    String? location,
    bool allday = false,
    String? userId,
    String? companyId,
  }) {
    return Events(
      eventName: eventName ?? this.eventName,
      eventStartTime: eventStartTime ?? this.eventStartTime,
      eventDuration: eventDuration ?? this.eventDuration,
      eventDate: eventDate ?? this.eventDate,
      eventDescription: eventDescription ?? this.eventDescription,
      location: location ?? this.location,
      allDay: allDay ?? this.allDay,
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
    );
  }
}

class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));
  EventsNotifier();  <<< ERROR APPEARS HERE

  @override
  Events build() {
    return Events(
      // Return the initial state
      eventName: '',
      eventStartTime: DateTime.now(),
      eventDuration: '',
      eventDate: DateTime.now(),
      eventDescription: '',
      location: '',
      allDay: false,
      userId: '',
      companyId: '',
    );
  }

  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? location;
  bool allDay;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  void updateEventname(String? newEventName) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventName: newEventName);
  }

  void updateeventStartTime(DateTime? newEventStartTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventStartTime: newEventStartTime);
  }

  void updateEventDuration(String? newEventDuration) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDuration: newEventDuration);
  }

  void updateEventDate(DateTime? newEventDate) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDate: newEventDate);
  }

  void updateEventDescription(String? newEventDescription) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDescription: newEventDescription);
  }

  void updateLocation(String? newLocation) {
    state = state.copyWith(location: newLocation);
  }

  void updateAllDay(bool newAllDay) {
    state = state.copyWith(allday: newAllDay);
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        location = firestore['location'],
        allDay = firestore['allDay'],
        userId = firestore['agentId'],
        companyId = firestore['agencyId'];

  saveEvent(Events events, String? eventDesc, [String? eventId]) {
    var newEvent = Events(
        eventName: events.eventName,
        eventStartTime: events.eventStartTime,
        eventDuration: events.eventDuration,
        eventDate: events.eventDate,
        eventDescription: events.eventDescription,
        location: events.location,
        allDay: events.allDay,
        companyId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId,
        userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId);

    if (eventId != null && eventId != '') {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(
          newEvent, ref, eventId); // Update existing event
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewEvent(false);
    } else {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(newEvent, ref); // Create new event
    }
  }

  deleteEvent(String? eventId) {
    firestoreService.deleteEvent(eventId, ref);
  }
}

final eventsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<EventsNotifier, Events>(() {
  return EventsNotifier();
});
```

How do I resolve this error?
Thanks

UPDATE:
This is what the class looks like now after I combined the answers from both comments:

```
class Events {
  String? id;
  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? location;
  late bool allDay;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  Events({
    this.id,
    this.eventName,
    this.eventStartTime,
    this.eventDuration,
    this.eventDate,
    this.eventDescription,
    this.location,
    this.allDay = false,
    this.userId,
    this.companyId,
  });

  // Reading data from firebase and converting it into Event type
  factory Events.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
    return Events(
      id: id,
      eventName: doc['eventName'],
      eventStartTime: (doc['eventStartTime'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDuration: doc['eventDuration'],
      eventDate: (doc['eventDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDescription: doc['eventDescription'],
      location: doc['location'],
      allDay: doc['allDay'],
      userId: doc['userId'],
      companyId: doc['companyId'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'location': location,
      'allDay': allDay,
      'agentId': userId,
      'agencyId': companyId,
    };
  }

  Events copyWith({
    String? eventName,
    DateTime? eventStartTime,
    String? eventDuration,
    DateTime? eventDate,
    String? eventDescription,
    String? location,
    bool allday = false,
    String? userId,
    String? companyId,
  }) {
    return Events(
      eventName: eventName ?? this.eventName,
      eventStartTime: eventStartTime ?? this.eventStartTime,
      eventDuration: eventDuration ?? this.eventDuration,
      eventDate: eventDate ?? this.eventDate,
      eventDescription: eventDescription ?? this.eventDescription,
      location: location ?? this.location,
      allDay: allDay ?? this.allDay,
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
    );
  }
}

class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));
  EventsNotifier();

  @override
  Events build() {
    return Events(
      // Return the initial state
      eventName: '',
      eventStartTime: DateTime.now(),
      eventDuration: '',
      eventDate: DateTime.now(),
      eventDescription: '',
      location: '',
      allDay: false,
      userId: '',
      companyId: '',
    );
  }

  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? location;
  late bool allDay;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  void updateEventname(String? newEventName) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventName: newEventName);
  }

  void updateeventStartTime(DateTime? newEventStartTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventStartTime: newEventStartTime);
  }

  void updateEventDuration(String? newEventDuration) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDuration: newEventDuration);
  }

  void updateEventDate(DateTime? newEventDate) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDate: newEventDate);
  }

  void updateEventDescription(String? newEventDescription) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDescription: newEventDescription);
  }

  void updateLocation(String? newLocation) {
    state = state.copyWith(location: newLocation);
  }

  void updateAllDay(bool newAllDay) {
    state = state.copyWith(allday: newAllDay);
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        location = firestore['location'],
        allDay = firestore['allDay'],
        userId = firestore['agentId'],
        companyId = firestore['agencyId'];

  saveEvent(Events events, String? eventDesc, [String? eventId]) {
    var newEvent = Events(
        eventName: events.eventName,
        eventStartTime: events.eventStartTime,
        eventDuration: events.eventDuration,
        eventDate: events.eventDate,
        eventDescription: events.eventDescription,
        location: events.location,
        allDay: events.allDay,
        companyId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId,
        userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId);

    if (eventId != null && eventId != '') {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(
          newEvent, ref, eventId); // Update existing event
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewEvent(false);
    } else {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(newEvent, ref); // Create new event
    }
  }

  deleteEvent(String? eventId) {
    firestoreService.deleteEvent(eventId, ref);
  }
}

final eventsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<EventsNotifier, Events>(() {
  return EventsNotifier();
});
```

Now, there are no errors. Thanks

Comment: Just change "allDay" parameter like these... -->  class Events {final bool allDay;  Events({ this.allDay = false}  Events copyWith({bool allday}}

Comment: You made `allDay` `late` for the `Events` class (which wasn't necessary) but not for the `EventsNotifier` class.   Pay attention to the line number in the error message.